# How to parse a json string to flat rows in SQL Server?

Tags: json, sql-server, json-query, open-json, json-value

I have data like below in a file which I read into a variable in SQL Server:

```
{
  "TypeCode": [
    {
      "DestinationValue": "Private",
      "SourceValue": "1"
    },
    {
      "DestinationValue": "Public",
      "SourceValue": "2"
    }
],
"TypeDesc": [
    {
      "DestinationValue": "Hello",
      "SourceValue": "1"
    },
    {
      "DestinationValue": "Bye",
      "SourceValue": "2"
    }
]
}
```

Now I need to convert this into data like below:

```
Name             SourceValue       DestValue
--------------------------------------------
TypeCode         1                 Hello
TypeCode         2                 Bye
```

Concern is - there can be many such arrays in this JSON and code should be automatically able to handle all of them without changing the code.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to parse the `"TypeDesc"` part of the input JSON?

Comment: Hi  @Zhorov -- yes .. There can be 15 or 20 such arrays so the output should reflect all of them. The resultset shown here is just parsing of the one array

Comment: Why do that in the *database*? Parse it before storing it and use proper tables to store what looks like lookup data. Or use OPENJSON to parse the data once and store it in lookup tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the input JSON using `OPENJSON()` twice (with default and  explicit schema):

```
SELECT j1.[key] AS Name, j2.SourceValue, j2.DestinationValue
FROM OPENJSON(@json) j1
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (
   SourceValue nvarchar(100) '$.SourceValue',
   DestinationValue nvarchar(100) '$.DestinationValue'
) j2
```

Result:

```
Name        SourceValue DestinationValue
TypeCode    1           Private
TypeCode    2           Public
TypeDesc    1           Hello
TypeDesc    2           Bye
```

Comment: Better yet, parse it on the client and store the data in *two* lookup tables. Or use this query to create proper lookup tables. This query can't use any indexes